# How to compare the similarity between real-world images and their binary representations?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, defects

I am working on the development of a defect detection task. When using a segmentation model for detection, I've found that it is not effective in detecting defects when copper lines are completely covered.

Therefore, I aim to compare a design blueprint (CAM) with the original image (after its transformation into binarized images) to identify the differences. The challenge lies in the fact that the circles in the design blueprint are outlined, while the binarized version of the actual image renders them solid. Consequently, subtracting the two images does not yield a meaningful result.

The example of original image and binarization image:

[The Original image(its transformation into binarized images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVPqH.png)

[The CAM Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsN3w.png)

Are there any algorithms or neural network approaches that can address this type of problem?

Comment: If possible, you should post the rgb and binary images that you want to compare. I don't know what a binary image from a CAM is (is it a black/white mask, grayscale, some weird proprietary format?). You should also show what you've tried already. It helps to demonstrate effort and prevents answerers from retreading old ground.

Comment: @IanChu I have updated the instructions along with example images.

Comment: for black/white masks like this where you expect things to be properly aligned subtraction is the correct way for checking for differences between the template and the manufactured item. The issue here is in how the item was masked. If the method you use for masking creates holes in the item where there are none, then that method isn't sufficient.